# Change footer classicthesis which loads scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: header-footer, classicthesis, scrlayer-scrpage

I am using the classicthesis style which loads scrlayer-scrpage. I like most parts about this style but want to change a few things. One thing I used to do in other documents is to place a colored box next to the page number in the footer. I normally did it like this:

```
  \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setlength{\textwidth}{146.8mm} % = 210mm - 37mm - 26.2mm
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{11.6mm} % 37mm - 1in (from hoffset)
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.8mm} % = 26.2mm - 1in (from hoffset)
\setlength{\topmargin}{-2.2mm} % = 0mm -1in + 23.2mm 
\setlength{\textheight}{221.9mm} % = 297mm -29.5mm -31.6mm - 14mm (12 to accomodate footline with pagenumber) 
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[EL]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\color{Black}\rule[0pt]{0.55\marginparwidth}    {6pt}\makebox[0.16\marginparwidth][r]{\bfseries\sffamily\color{black}\fontspec[]    {MetaBoldLF-Roman}\thepage}}}%
\fancyfoot[OR]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[0.16\marginparwidth][1]{\bfseries\sffamily\color{black}\fontspec[]{MetaBoldLF-Roman}\thepage}\color{Blac}\rule[0pt]{0.55\marginparwidth}{6pt}}}%
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot[EL]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\color{black}\rule[0pt]    {0.55\marginparwidth}{6pt}\makebox[0.16\marginparwidth][r]    {\bfseries\sffamily\color{black}\fontspec[]{MetaBoldLF-Roman}\thepage}}}%
    \fancyfoot[OR]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[0.16\marginparwidth][l]    {\bfseries\sffamily\color{black}\fontspec[]{MetaBoldLF-Roman}\thepage}\color{black}\rule[0pt]{0.55\marginparwidth}{6pt}}}}%
\fancypagestyle{addpagenumbersforpdfimports}{
    \fancyhead{}
    \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    \fancyfoot{}
    \fancyfoot[EL]{\makebox[0pt][r]{\color{black}\rule[0pt]   {0.55\marginparwidth}{6pt}\makebox[0.16\marginparwidth][r] {\bfseries\sffamily\color{black}\fontspec[]{MetaBoldLF-Roman}\thepage}}}%
    \fancyfoot[OR]{\makebox[0pt][l]{\makebox[0.16\marginparwidth][l]    {\bfseries\sffamily\color{black}\fontspec[]{MetaBoldLF-Roman}\thepage}\color{black}\rule[0pt]{0.55\marginparwidth}{6pt}}}}%


\begin{document}
    \chapter{hello Word}
    Hello world
    \chapter{hello Word2}
    Hello world 2
\end{document}
```

Can somebody help me translate this to the classicthesis file? Also want it to appear on the chapter starting pages.

Comment: Current version of `classicthesis` uses `scrlayer-scrpage` not `scrpage2`.

Comment: Please ask only one question per question.

Comment: Indeed it is scrlayer-scrpage. I edidted the question accordingly and deleted the second question... I do have no idea how to achieve what i want tho.

Comment: Sorry, cannot help. Do not have "MetaBoldLF-Roman". You should remove everything that is not needed for the problem.

Comment: Ok thanks for the hint... after reading the documentation i smply needed to add a \rofoot option in the style file.... But page where a chapter starts i still have a plain number . How do i change this specific pages as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question, your example does currently not really show, what you want, because it does not show the page number in the page foot on even pages or chapter pages. So I cannot decide whether or not the following is really what you expect:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn]{book}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setlength{\textwidth}{146.8mm} % = 210mm - 37mm - 26.2mm
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{11.6mm} % 37mm - 1in (from hoffset)
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0.8mm} % = 26.2mm - 1in (from hoffset)
\setlength{\topmargin}{-2.2mm} % = 0mm -1in + 23.2mm 
\setlength{\textheight}{221.9mm} % = 297mm -29.5mm -31.6mm - 14mm (12 to accomodate footline with pagenumber) 
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}
% Put \marginparwidth onto the page
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{\dimexpr\paperwidth-\oddsidemargin-1in-\textwidth-\marginparsep}

\usepackage[footwidth=textwithmarginpar]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}
\rofoot*{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax]{%
    \pagemark\hfill\rule{.55\marginparwidth}{6pt}%
  }%
}
\lefoot*{%
  \makebox[\dimexpr\marginparsep+\marginparwidth\relax]{%
    \rule{.55\marginparwidth}{6pt}\hfill\pagemark
  }%
}

\usepackage{mwe}

\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image: first page]
[image: second and third page]

If you want to change the font at the page footer, just use something like

```
\setkomafont{pagefoot}{\bfseries}% You can also use \fontspec here.
```

If you want to change the color of the rule, e.g. red color, use either

```
\textcolor{red}{\rule{.55\marginparwidth}{6pt}}
```

or

```
\addtokomafont{pagefoot}{\color{red}}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\normalcolor}
```

Comment: That was almost exactly what i wanted ! thank you very much!!

Comment: What is missing is the possibility to change the color of the box?

Comment: @NorrinRad: Do you know command `\textcolor`? If not, read the manual of package `color`. You can use it to change the color of the `\rule{…}{…}`.